# PHP SimpleXML fatal error when using addChild on a concatenated var

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, addchild

I'm trying to use the addChild function on a concatenated var, and it doesn't seem to work. I suppose it comes from the object type of the argument but I can't seem to be able to put the finger on it.
When I try with the standard var, it works :

```
$prnp = $ndprofileASz2tnrap_portrestrictions->addChild('portRestriction');
```

But when I try with multiple vars, an error shows up:

```
$asversion = 'z2tnrap';
$nppr = '$ndprofileAS'.$asversion.'_portrestrictions';
$prnp = $nppr->addChild('portRestriction');
```

If I "echo" the $nppr var, I get the correct var, but the addChild function results in the error message: "Fatal error: Call to a member function addChild() on a non-object".

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`$nppr` will just be a string at that point. it's not a simplexml object anymore. As well, your syntax is incorrect:

```
$nppr = '$ndprofileAS'.$asversion.'_portrestrictions';
        ^-           ^-
```

variables in single-quoted strings are NOT interpolated. You're inserting a literal `$`, a literal `n`, a literal `d`, etc.. into your strin, not the value of the $ndprofileAS variable.

Comment: Thanks, so, is there a way to have this variable interpreted as a Simplexml object (while keeping the concatenation of multiple vars) ?

Comment: I have no idea what your code is actually trying to accomplish, or how you got to that snippet, so.. no.. sorry, can't help you.

Comment: Well, I get the "asversion" from a form which determines where I'm going to add a subnode. I already have the main nodes ($ndprofileASz2tnrap_portrestrictions and others) created but listing all these nodes in "if" conditions would take forever (and be terribly disgustin), so I'm concatenating the constant part with the specific name. Is there a way to parse that string in a SimpleXML Element ?